# How do i add one row with button with "document.createTextNode"

Tags: javascript, html

```
  var cell_masuk  = newRow.insertCell(5);
  var newText  = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("tanggal_masuk").value);
  cell_masuk.appendChild(newText);

  var cell_exp  = newRow.insertCell(6);
  var newText  = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("tanggal_kadaluarsa").value);
  cell_exp.appendChild(newText);

  var cell_btn  = newRow.insertCell(7);
  var newText  = document.createTextNode("<input type='button' class='button' value='x'>");
  cell_btn.appendChild(newText);
```

From the code above i want to insert new table row with button on it. But when i use this code:

```
var cell_btn  = newRow.insertCell(7);
var newText  = document.createTextNode("<input type='button' class='button' value='x'>");
cell_btn.appendChild(newText);
```

The result on my table is always string.
Sorry for my bad English, im new on web developing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name says, `createTextNode` creates a text node. The content you provide is taken literally, as characters to display.

If you want to create an `input` element, you want [`createElement("input")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement):

```
var cell_btn  = newRow.insertCell(7);
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "button";
input.className = "button";
input.value = "x";
cell_btn.appendChild(input);
```

Alternately, if you prefer to work with markup, you can use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML):

```
var cell_btn  = newRow.insertCell(7);
cell_btn.insertAdjacentHTML(
    "beforeend",
    "<input type='button' class='button' value='x'>"
);
```

Comment: you beat me to it. +1

Comment: @T.J. Crowder i tried adding a 'onClick' on the button
with input.onClick = DeleteRow(index); but it doesnt work well, can u show show me the right syntax? Thanks before :)